# Passing 1 list of two tuples or list of lists into scipy interp1d function

Tags: python, list, scipy

Currently I'm passing data into `interp1d` like this:

```
x_  = [4,5,6,7,8]
y_  = [146,228,350,493,637]

y_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x_, y_)
print y_interp(5.6)

-> 301.2
```

Is it possible to pass data as a list of tuple pairs or list of lists?

```
data = [[4,146],[5,228],[6,350],[7,493],[8,637]]

# or

data = [(4,146),(5,228),(6,350),(7,493),(8,637)]


y_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(data)
print y_interp(5.6)

-> error..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to aggregate the tuples (or lists) together and then unpack your two new sequences as arguments

```
>>> data = [(4,146),(5,228),(6,350),(7,493),(8,637)]
>>> y_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(*zip(*data))
301.2
```

---

**Edit**:

Since you're only reformulating your data for the purpose of passing it and working with Python 2.x, better would be [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) such that you only produce an iterable and don't have the overhead of a list.